# How to set queue name in hadoop using new API

Tags: java, hadoop

I see that in old `API` `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf` class had `setQueueName` which was used to set the queue name in `hadoop` .
Can anyone point me to equivalent `API` using new classes in `org.apache.hadoop.conf` or `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` class to set the configuration as shown below

```
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename", queueName);
```